# Constraint for a decoration: only if edge is long enough

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Title+Picture might make you guess my question:

[image]

My goal is to modify the tikz-style `companion` such that in this example the `text along path`-decoration will only be shown if it fits, i.e. between a,b but not between b,c.
More precisely, I want the style to

1. compute the length `Le` of the edge it is applied to,
2. compute the length `Ld` of its decoration-text,
3. check, whether `Le ≥ Ld + c` holds, where `c` is some constant for a minimal margin) and
4. only if that is the case, apply the decoration.

Minimal standalone source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[companion/.style={->,
    postaction={
        decorate,decoration={raise=2pt,text along path,text color=purple!60!black,text={|\tiny|companion},text align=center}
    }
},node distance=1.2cm,>=stealth',auto]
\node[draw] (t3) at (1,0) {$c$};
\node[draw] (t1) at (0,0) {$b$} edge[companion] (t3);
\node[draw] (t2) at (-2,0) {$a$} edge[companion,bend left] (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I hope there is an elegant but dynamic solution.

Comment: You can either hack into text decoration or define a new metadecoration. Is it going to be always the same text `comapnion`?

Comment: Well, for now yes, it's always the same text. However, with respect to that, the solution should be easily customizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were defining a new decoration, you could do this with the key `switch if less than=<dim> to <state>`.  Fortunately, it isn't too hard to add this to the current decoration.  We have to do it after the text length has been computed, so we hook into the `left indent` state.  I haven't taken into account the right margin, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67470/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text,arrows}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/decoration/omit long text/.code={%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgf@decorate@@text along path@left indent@options\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname pgf@decorate@@text along path@left indent@options\endcsname,switch if less than=\pgf@lib@dec@text@width to final}%
  },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[companion/.style={->,
    postaction={
        decorate,decoration={raise=2pt,omit long text,text along path,text color=purple!60!black,text={|\tiny|companion},text align=center}
    }
},node distance=1.2cm,>=stealth',auto]
\node[draw] (t3) at (1,0) {$c$};
\node[draw] (t1) at (0,0) {$b$} edge[companion] (t3);
\node[draw] (t2) at (-2,0) {$a$} edge[companion,bend left] (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[companion/.style={->,
    postaction={
        decorate,decoration={raise=2pt,text along path,text color=purple!60!black,text={|\tiny|companion},text align=center}
    }
},node distance=1.2cm,>=stealth',auto]
\node[draw] (t3) at (1,0) {$c$};
\node[draw] (t1) at (0,0) {$b$} edge[companion] (t3);
\node[draw] (t2) at (-2,0) {$a$} edge[companion,bend left] (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Text decoration with long text suppressed]