# Constraint for a decoration: how to know result after decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

My question is kind of extending of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67470/constraint-for-a-decoration-only-if-edge-is-long-enough) answer. I want to decorate a path with text only when text fit the path, but also I want to know if decoration was success. I need to know this to be able to call decoration again with shorter text. I need this to implement solution for my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151060/tikz-text-alignment-and-line-breaking).

Currently I end up with modifying decoration along path myself using `\makeatletter .. \makeatother` in document preambule. I just copy text decoration implementation in my preambule and add the setting flag to the end of the `persistent precomputation = {..}` of the inital state in the following way:

```
\newif\iffit

\pgfdeclaredecoration{my text along path}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[
    width=+0pt,
    next state=left indent,
    persistent precomputation = {
      ...
      \ifdim\pgf@lib@dec@text@width<\pgfdecoratedpathlength
        \global \fittrue
      \else
        \global \fitfalse
      \fi
    }]{}
```

And then I can use `\iffit` in my code to check if decoration if successful. Is there more elegant solution for such case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Add the following

```
\makeatletter
    \pgfutil@namedef{pgf@decorate@@text along path@left indent@code}{
        \ifdim\pgf@lib@dec@text@width>\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance
            \tikzerror{text too long}
        \fi
    }
\makeatother
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358705/51022 for more information.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \pgfutil@namedef{pgf@decorate@@text along path@left indent@code}{
        \ifdim\pgf@lib@dec@text@width>\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance
            \tikzerror{text too long}
        \fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
        text={Is this text long enough to trigger the error?}}}]
        (0,0)--(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```