# Letterspacing in TiKZ text decorations

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontspec, decorations

I have a drawing of a circle with some text following the curve, as below:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

    \fontspec{Times New Roman}
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50.0}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw [
                thick,
                   postaction={
                        decorate,
                        decoration={
                              raise=-4.5ex,
                              text along path, 
                              reverse path,
                              text align={left},
                              text={A bunch of text}
                        }
                   },
                ] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);

    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

What I want, obviously, is expanded spacing between letters, but it looks like TiKZ is treating each word as a letter, and increasing the space between words. Is there a way to get letterspacing in this situation, and if so what is it?

Comment: Do you want to fill the entire path of the circle or just part of it? If it is the entire path you have two options: `text align = fit to path` or `text align = fit to path stretching spaces`. If you only want to fill part of the circle you need a new path and then chose either of the above `text align` options. See p596 of the TikZ manual.

Comment: I think an explanation of this strange `tikz` behavior is given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358705/101651.

Comment: @Ross That worked; if you want the credit, post as an answer & I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two text alignment options are available for the `decoration` key in `TikZ` that permit fitting text to a path. `fit to path` decorates the path by adjusting the spacing between characters. `fit to path stretching spaces` decorates the path by increasing the spacing between words.

The MWE provides and illustration of both these options, first using `fit to path` and the second example with `fit to path stretching spaces`. The third example demonstrates how to format text along the path. See the comments in the MWE for details.

This is the output:

[image]

This is the MWE, which must be compiled with `XeLaTex` or `LuaLaTex` because `fontspec` is loaded to use `Time New Roman` font:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex 
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

    \fontspec{Times New Roman}
%    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50.0} <- Not applicable here

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw [ rotate=145, % <- add rotation to get "A" at the top
                thick,
                   postaction={
                        decorate,
                        decoration={
                              raise=-4.5ex,
                              text along path, 
                              reverse path,
                              text align=fit to path, % <- spaces added between each character
                              text={ {\qquad} %<- Creates space between the first and last letter
                                   A bunch of text
                                   }
                        }
                   },
                ] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [ rotate=180,
                thick,
                postaction={
                    decorate,
                    decoration={
                        raise=-4.5ex,
                        text along path, 
                        reverse path,
                        text align=fit to path stretching spaces, % <- spaces between words increased
                        text={ {\qquad}
                             A bunch of text
                             }
                    }
                },
        ] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);        
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [ rotate=180,
            thick,
            postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                raise=-4.5ex,
                text along path, 
                reverse path,
                text align=fit to path,
                text={ {\qquad} % <- enclose macro in {}
                    |\Large\color{blue}| % <- Define the formatting of the text enclosed by |
                    A bunch 
                    |\LARGE\bfseries\color{red}| % <- Change the formatting 
                    of text
                }
            }
        },
    ] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```